# Are there any web3 libraries for react-native or for android light-client?

Tags: web3js, light-clients, android, whisper

I want to create a chat application using the whisper protocol for android platform 
, But I'm trying to use the current web3 package with react-native but I'm unable to use it as web3 package has some node core libraries which can't be used for react native, I also tried the mobile light-client library in android but it doesn't seem to have any apis to interact with whisper other than enabling whisper on the node, Can anyone help me with how can I use whisper in mobile devices??